# Origem e significado da expressão "estar encostado à box"

Tags: significado, português-europeu, expressões, origem

É relativamente comum ouvir esta expressão em Portugal continental. Por exemplo,

> Pergunta: Queres mais camarões?
>
> Resposta: Não, já **estou encostado à box**.

Comment: Eu conheço-a no plural, estar encostado às boxes.

Comment: @ANeves, a expressão é comum em Portugal?

Comment: @Schilive é sim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> encostado à box

A expressão é inspirada nos desportos automobilísticos, em particular as corridas de circuito como os *grande prêmio* (*grand prix*) da Formula 1. Vem do inglês [*pit stop*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pit_stop) (*paragem nas* ***boxes***) em que cada equipa tem a sua ***box***.

O significado da expressão é simplesmente ter parado.

Comment: Parar temporariamente, como num pit stop, ou permanentemente (se aposentar, etc.)? É comum essa expressão em pt-PT? Nunca tinha ouvido antes, acho que essencialmente não existe em pt-BR.

Comment: pit box stop or pit box